# TFS 2010 Build Agent DLL References outside branch

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, build-agent

We've got a project in source control:

```
$/Project/Trunk/Project.sln
```

most of the projects live under the trunk

```
$/Project/Trunk/Website
$/Project/Trunk/BLL
etc.
```

The problem is, they all reference DLLs stored in

```
$/Project/Common
```

When I try to build using the build agent, I get an error saying it can't find the DLLs in the $/Common folder.

I've run VS on the build agent machine and done a get latest on the $/Project/Common folder. I've also done a get latest on the $/Project/ and managed to build it myself on the build agent machine without issue.

How can I convince the build agent to look in the `$/Project/Common` folder (or where it maps to `D:\Source\Project\Common`) during builds?

Whilst this does highlight the fact that those DLL references should point below the branch, we're not going to be able to change the structure for a month or so due to business requirements (it works at the moment, automated builds are nice but not critical, getting upcoming releases out *is* critical) so any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Workspaces in the Build definition to change where the Project/Common folder is getting mapped to. You will want to change the verbosity of the build log (found in the Process tab in the Build Definition) to something like Detailed or Diagnostic to get a list of where files are getting put on disk when the TFS Build is running.  Then from there you can figure out how to alter the mappings in the Workspaces to get the files output to disk correctly

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try tomorrow. Are you aware if paths to references are absolute or relative?

Comment: Ok, that's thrown up some different issues but I think I'm past the source location issue. Thank you very much for such a helpful answer - Not only did you answer the Q but you anticipated my next one (Log level).